# Order string contains number (Linq, C#)

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq, sorting

I have string with numbers:

```
string s1 = "cos555cos";
string s2 = "coscos1";
string s3 = "22coscos";
string s4 = "333coscos";
string s5 = "cosco444s";
```

I made a list:

```
IList<string> test = new List<string>();
test.Add(s1);
test.Add(s2);
test.Add(s3);
test.Add(s4);
test.Add(s5);
```

How to order it by number. The result should be like:

**s2,
s3,
s4,
s5,
s1**

```
foreach (var item in test)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: How would you order `BBBB123BBB`, `AAAA123AAA` ?

Comment: or `22BBBBB333`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    string s1 = "cos555cos";
    string s2 = "coscos1";
    string s3 = "22coscos";
    string s4 = "333coscos";
    string s5 = "cosco444s";


    IList<string> test = new List<string>();
    test.Add(s1);
    test.Add(s2);
    test.Add(s3);
    test.Add(s4);
    test.Add(s5);


    var orderedEnumerable = test.OrderBy(StripNumeric);

    foreach (string s in orderedEnumerable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }


    int StripNumeric(string input)
    {
        Regex digitsOnly = new Regex(@"[^\d]");
        return int.Parse(digitsOnly.Replace(input, ""));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

order it by convert to int the matches of this regex:

```
\d+
```

something like:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+");
IList<string> test2 = new List<string>();
foreach(var item in test)
{
    Match match = r.match(item);
    test2.Add(match[0]);
}
Sort(test2);
```

Comment: hi, this something wrong **match[0]);** and **Sort** ? I know that into foreach need to be test2 or ....

Comment: That is just the idea.